Texture Paint draw tool not working
I've been having trouble painting the texture on this character. I've tried with most of the things that I've seen on tutorials but none of them have worked so far.
On the image editor -> paint window when i use the fill tool i can see the changes on the texture of the model, but when i paint over it with the draw tool nothings happens. Neither the texture nor the texture map have a texture.
Here's the link to the project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bnK13pPC6-_19_Ssu4F4hVYsFpeKkgkz/view?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance

Disable the Remesh modifier, it probably breaks the UVs and causes problem to display the texture. Also close the texture that you have loaded in the brush settings, as it is completely black it prevents to paint anything:


Thanks a bunch, that fixed it.
